# Strange behavior of LET function with MIN/MAX applifed to an array

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-365

Assume that cells A1:C1 contain

```
100, 300, 40
```

When A2 contains:

```
=LET(x,A1,x*2)
```

and is copied to B2:B3, the output is `200,600, 80`, as expected.

If A2 contains

```
=LET(x,A1,MIN(x,150))
```

and is copied over again, the output is `100, 150, 40`, also as expected.

Now moving to range notation, if A2 contains

```
=LET(x,A1:C1,x*2)
```

the output spills into B2:B3 - `200,600, 80`, as again expected.

But, if A2 contains

```
=LET(x,A1:C1,MIN(x,150))
```

The output does NOT spill and A2 is `40`!

The effect is the same for MAX, SUM, etc. and both the desktop and web versions of Excel.

Is that a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: MIN,MAX,SUM and others allow the use of arrays as entry and return a single number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MIN,MAX,SUM and others allow the use of arrays as entry and return a single number.

In this instance just using a simple `IF()` instead will acccomplish what is desired:

```
=LET(x,A1:C1,y,150,IF(x<=y,x,y))
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, the good ol' "replace min/max with `if(a>b[etc.])`"... I guess I have to live with it. So three points for the benefit of our grandchildren: (i) documentation should have been (much) clearer about this; (ii) what if some innocent bystander wanted to use AVERAGE instead of MIN/MAX? and (iii) I going to try to fold the whole thing into a LAMBDA and see if my computer bursts into flames! Oh, yes, and thanks!